# Generic Linq query to get array of entities with specified keys

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, generics

I need a generic query for something like this but couldn't find anything in web (maybe because of bad search!)

```
int[] ids = new int[]{1,2,3} 
var q = context.where(o=> ids.contains(o.id));
```

in which my entity type is unknown but I'm sure that:

1. The primary key is single
2. The primary key type is `int`
3. I **cannot** change the entity definition

So the signature is something like this :

```
Public IQueryable<T> GetRecords(int[] keys)
{
   var dbset = context.Set<T>();
   ...//the generic query
}
```

Also it is important to have a same SQL output (to have a same performance) in generic and non-generic implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private IDictionary<Type, string> _primaryKeyCache = new Dictionary<Type, string>();

public IQueryable<T> GetRecords(int[] keys)
{
   var dbSet = context.Set<T>();

   var type = typeof(T);

   string primaryKeyName;
   if(!_primaryKeyCache.TryGetValue(type, out primaryKeyName)){
      var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;
      var set = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<YourEntity>();
      var keyName = set.EntitySet.ElementType
                                            .KeyMembers
                                            .Select(k => k.Name)
                                            .First();

      _primaryKeyCache[type] = primaryKeyName = keyName;
   }

   return dbSet.DynamicContains<T, int>(primaryKeyName, keys);
}

private static IQueryable<T> DynamicContains<T, TProperty>(
        this IQueryable<T> query, 
        string property, 
        IEnumerable<TProperty> items)
    {
        var pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var me = Expression.Property(pe, property);
        var ce = Expression.Constant(items); 
        var call = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Contains", new[] { me.Type }, ce, me);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(call, pe);
        return query.Where(lambda);
    }
```

That should do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem using polymorphism. Crete an interface that declares an integer `Id` property and implement in your entities, since it is common for all of them. Then have a constraint on the generic parameter `T` that forces it to be a type that implements your interface, so the compiler will know that the `T` will be a type that has `Id` property and you will be able to access it:

```
// IId is the interface that should be implemented
public IQueryable<T> GetRecords<T>(int[] keys) where T : IId
{
   var dbset = context.Set<T>();
    ...//the generic query
}
```

Comment: I know this but I need a generic solution if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Create an new interface, e.g. IKeyedByIntEntity

```
public interface IKeyedByIntEntity
{
  int Key { get; }
}
```

Have all entities to be used in the query implement the interface. In an ideal world, the field has the same name so you can use that as the property name in the interface and thus not have to change the implementation of your entities.

```
public class MyEntity : IKeyedByIntEntity
{
  public int Key { get; set; }
  public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Update your GetRecords function or class to require the interface, something like one of these...

```
public class Fetch
{
  public IQueryable<T> GetRecords<T>(int[] keys)
    where T : IKeyedByIntEntity
  {
    IQueryable<T> records = this.context.Where(e => keys.Contains(e.Key));
    return records;
  }
}

public class Fetch<T> where T : IKeyedByIntEntity
{
  public IQueryable<T> GetRecords(int[] keys)
  {
    IQueryable<T> records = this.context.Where(e => keys.Contains(e.Key));
    return records;
  }
}
```

Comment: Same as Selman22 solution. I know this way but as I mentioned in my question I need a "Generic" approach

Comment: Define "generic" for your needs please. You're probably approaching towards the realm of using Reflection.